# Unity C# How to reference a subscript in another script?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In the following script, I get the error  "Inaccessible due to protection level.":

```
public class WrongAnswerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        GameManager.UpdateMistakes(1);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the GameManager class which manages the update:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> targets;
    public TextMeshProUGUI mistakeText;
    public int mistakes;

    void Start()
    {    
            mistakes = 0;
            mistakeText.text = "Mistakes: " + mistakes;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void UpdateMistakes(int mistakesToAdd)
    {
        mistakes += mistakesToAdd;
        mistakeText.text = "Mistakes: " + mistakes;
    }
}
```

How should I correctly initiate my script ? I am pretty new to C# so I struggle to understand the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the function public so that it becomes accessible.

```
public void UpdateMistakes(int mistakesToAdd)
```

You might need to make sure that you reference an existing instance of the GameManager that is somewhere in your scene.

```
private bool HasBeenClicked = false;
void OnMouseDown()
{
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    //Only do this block when you have not clicked before
    if (!HasBeenClicked)
    {
        //get a reference to the gamemanager that is already somewhere in the scene
        GameManager gameManager = (GameManager)FindObjectOfType(typeof(GameManager));
        gameManager.UpdateMistakes(1);
        HasBeenClicked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: public and static, if they want to access with `GameManager.UpdateMistakes(1);`

Comment: I expected it to be a singleton seeing how public int mistakes isn't static neither.

Comment: Ive recieved some errors on the 2nd script. "typeOf does not exist in current context" and "GameManager is a type which is not valid in given context"

Comment: i made a typo there where typeof is all lowercase. i adjusted it in the answer. that should fix both issues. if not ill try and keep an eye out on the comments here

Comment: Thankyou so much for this, ive got it working now but was wondering how i could make it so that a number can only increment once instead of infinitely? Would this be possible?

Comment: only once per clickable object or only once in total?

Comment: Once per clickable object so once the player has pressed the button once pressing it again will not increment the mistake counter

Comment: I adjusted the answer to include this request :)

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help. one final thing im trying to do is get 2 of these done, one for mistakes and one for number of questions answered but I am getting this error. https://pasteboard.co/IYtraln.png many thanks.

Comment: I had a day off yesterday and didnt check the site, but the error seems to be in both line 23 and 37 where you have a semicolon behind question, followed by more code for that line. replace the semicolons by plusses and it should work.